# How to configure Phpunit.xml to use multiple browsers in Phpunit test with selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy, browsers, phpunit

I'm working on automation test for a big project and I'm using `Phpunit` for functional test and as a server `selenium webdriver`.

I want to execute many tests using `different browsers`, I don't know what's the appropriate configuration to addend my objective, it's in `phpunit.xml` or in the test class, because in the `SetUp() method` I can work only with one browser.

This is my `SetUp()` method

```
 public function setUp()
 {
    $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'internet explorer');
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://10.157.3.206:4570/wd/hub',$capabilities);
 }
```

I tried to follow this Link :

http://elnur.pro/using-environment-variables-to-add-flexibility-to-phpunit-tests
But Error is generated , `Class Browser Not found`

Can anyone help me to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** :

- Must understand we can not run `phpunit` tests on multiple browser simultaneously
- Running test on one browser at a time is only possible option
- Following snippet is demonstrating default firefox browser for execution

  ```
  class myUnitTest extends PHPUnit_Selenium2TestCase {
      try {
         public $browser = getenv("SELENIUM_BROWSER");
      } catch (Exception $e) {
         public $browser = "firefox";
      }
      public function setUp() {
         $this->setBrowser("*".$browser);
      }
   }
  ```